# android java call log

Tags: java, android, listview

Помогите пожалуйста! Как в масив *phonesArray* вывести номера с журнала звонков. Только номера. Чтоб потом вывести списком.

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CallLog;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener {


    final String[] phonesArray = new String[]{"0931111111", "0932222222", "0933333333",
            "0934444444", "0935555555"};
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> phonesList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(phonesArray));
    private View v;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, phonesList);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(this);

    }



    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        String apiUrl = "https://yandex.ua/search/?text=";
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
         Uri.parse(apiUrl + l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                selectedItem + " ok.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Обновление**

С получением решил. Как теперь по клику искать номер в яндексе?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor,
            new String[] { CallLog.Calls.NUMBER},
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```